# web api Bad Request when getting access token after moving to production

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api that is working great in test using an access token / bearer authentication.  I authenticate and make requests using HttpClient.  Easy.

Here is the basic web client setup.  The base address is a constant that I change when moving to production.

```
    public static HttpClient GetClient()
    {

        HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();

        Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Ics2Constants.ICS2APIBaseAddress);
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        return Client;
    }
```

I build the token request login info like so:

```
       var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        values.Add("grant_type", "password");
        values.Add("username", "niceUser");
        values.Add("password", "NiCePaSsWord");
        var loginContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
```

And then I make the request for the access token:

```
        var loginResponse = await client.PostAsync("/Token", loginContent);
```

In test mode, perfect.  I can get my access token, pass it back on subsequent requests.  All is good.

When I move to production.  I get a bad request 400 on the request for access token.  I do have the base address right because if I take off the authorize attribute I can get data back.

Something is different about the request for access token in production, but I have no clue what to change.

Comment: Sounds like a CORS issue.

Comment: Don't see much on CORS using the HttpClient... how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer ended up being two part:

1)  Issue with the web host.  They had a corruption on their end.

2)  After they fixed their issue I still received a 404 (not found)... so I had to take out the "/" in my PostAsync.  So the new line looks like so:

```
var loginResponse = await client.PostAsync("Token", loginContent);
```

It worked in debug on the local side with the "/", but the production side was not happy.

I'm up and working now.  :)

Comment: It is an intresting note. I have some trouble here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937328/get-asp-net-mvc5-webapi-token-fails-sometimes?noredirect=1#comment61433985_36937328  and will check your solution